# Nginx server name without www pointing to wrong virtual host

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have a Rails app and a Ghost blog installed on my server with Nginx as the web server.
I want blog.example.com to point to my blog and everything else to point to main App.

My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name blog.example.com;
root /root/ghost;

location / {
    ...blah
  }
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com, *.example.com;
  root /home/example/current/public/;
  gzip_static on;

  location / {
    ...blah
  }
}
```

However if I omit the www in the domain, it goes to the blog instead of app.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server_name` is space-separated, not comma-separated. It should be `server_name example.com *.example.com;`.